Error while changing Kernel Size in my densenet201 model
My densenet201 model works well only with kernel_size = 7 , any modification  to kernel size throws this error:

Detector thread - 5299:Error in the detector thread mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (5x48000 and 1920x576), PID 5394, None

I have tried adjusting input and output shapes accordingly but it still throws the same error.
The code:
class ModifiedDenseNet(torch.nn.Module):
            def __init__(self, old_model, nb_classes):
                super(ModifiedDenseNet, self).__init__()
                self.features = old_model.features
                self.mixer = torch.nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=7, stride=1)
                self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(1920, nb_classes)  
            def forward(self, x):
                x = self.features(x)
                x = self.mixer(x)
                f = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
                x = self.classifier(f)
                return f, x

        return ModifiedDenseNet(model, 576)

Suggest me necessary changes.
I want to optimize the model processing by changing parameters.
How should I change Kernel Size?
I tried flattening the output features to adjust accordingly for classifier layer after changing the kernel size, I even tried removing pooling layer but it still threw errors.
By adjusting pooling parameters I am expecting faster processing of inputs through the model.
